# setting backgroung image to button tag in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i tried to set image to the button tag in asp.net but it gave an error saying background-image cannot be applied to . Please help
I wrote the following code

```
<asp:Button ID="bsrc" runat="server" Style="left: 545px; position: absolute; top: 18px;font-family:Tahoma; font-size:small" Text="Search" Width="101px" />
<img src="search-icon.png" alt="" style="left: 649px; width: 29px; position: absolute; top: 17px; height: 26px" />
```

Comment: can you post your html/asp.net code?

Comment: i got error while setting backgroung-image in style attribute

Comment: can you actually post the code that's giving the error?

Comment: the code that i have posted above gave me error when i add background-image in the style attribute

Comment: Yes, but you may be specifying the attribute wrong, the image path, any extra quotes used, etc

Comment: in asp to use image i need to have image in the same folder where all other files are...so i just gave the image name in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an asp.net control called ImageButton which looks as though it is what you are wanting to use.

```
<asp:ImageButton id="bsrc" runat="server" ImageUrl="search-icon.png" />
```

Rather than using a button and then trying to give it an image.

Edit:

To display text, you can't use the ImageButton. So you will need to use some css to achive the background image of the button.

CSS

```
.btnstyle1{ background: url(yourimageurl.jpg); height: imageheight; width: imagewidth; }
```

Button

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button 1" CssClass="btnstyle1" />
```

Comment: +1 - this way you lose UseSubmitBehavior but gain alternate and descriptive properties.

Comment: but how do i display text on <asp:ImageButton>

Comment: Please, lead by example: `but` is an awful identifier, it doesn't describe the nature of itself one iota.