# How to change the background image of an image button

Tags: asp.net

I have an `ImageButton` as follows:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageBtn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("locationname") %>'
```

Now on hover i want to change the background image. The background image is in an `Img` folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting backgroung image to button tag in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389865/setting-backgroung-image-to-button-tag-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the aspx file:

```
<asp:ImageButton id="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/Image1.jpg"></asp:ImageButton>
```

In the aspx.cs file, Page_Load event handler:

```
ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.src = 'Images/Image2.jpg'");
ImageButton1.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.src = 'Images/Image1.jpg'");
```